# Align child to the bottom of the parent in CSS (Flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flexbox and I am trying to align a child division to the bottom of a parent division. I can't find a solution. Here's an example of what I tried.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
    height: 70%;
}

.bottom {
    height: 30%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='top'>
        <p>Content to go on top</p>
    </div>
    <div class='bottom'>
        <p>Content to go on bottom</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I end up with:
[I am trying to make that happen to the left sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mycd.png)

Comment: Try using align-items : top; , align-items:bottom;

Comment: @BuggyParadox Didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `.bottom` a flex container to be able to use `justify-content`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  border:1px solid;
}

.top {
  height: 70%;
  border:1px solid;
}

.bottom {
  height: 30%;
  display: flex; /*added this*/
  flex-direction: column; /*added this*/
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='top'>
    <p>Content to go on top</p>
  </div>
  <div class='bottom'>
    <p>Content to go on bottom</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!